# Using Character as Naming Convention in R

Tags: r

I am analyzing a data set and have created a function that summarizes most of my columns. The goal of my script is to automate the creation and extraction of summary tables(more or less dataframes).

To generalize as much as possible, I want to pass a character string to my function to be used to name columns, rows, files and more.

What I am working with currently:

```
NameFun <- function(df, name) {

##Name the first column
colnames(df)[1] <- "name"  

##Write DF to Excel Workbook
write.xlsx(df, "Workbook.xlsx", sheetName = "name", 
           col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, append = TRUE)

}
```

The objective here is to input a character "name" and use it within the function. I have tried "eval", "assign", and "get" with no luck. I have tried a few other attempts but either R doesn't recognize it in the environment, does nothing at all, or rejects the idea of passing a character all together.

I am open to any other solutions as to help generalize my script even more. Each column will have a unique name but report the same number of columns and type of metrics. Ideally, I would be able to pass a list of each column to the function and loop it through the whole data set.

Thanks!

-J

Comment: Don't quote `name` inside of the function body, since it is a parameter -- quoting it causes it to be interpreted as the string `"name"`, not the variable `name`

Comment: Do not use `"name"` but rather `name` since this is a variable

Comment: Unfortunate, that doesn't solve the problem. Taking out quotes and passing the variable into the function doesn't yield any result; the function doesn't do anything. Adding quotes to the passed varaible throws this error:

Comment: Error in colnames(df)[1] <- name : 
  incompatible types (from closure to character) in subassignment type fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do this:

```
#Initialize a list to hold your results
ll<-list()

# You can run a loop or run it multiple times to generate your summary
ll[[name]]<-summary_Method(...) # Or pass the df
NameFun<-function(name, ll, df){
  ll[[name]]<-df
}

# Write the list of dataframe to excel file.
lapply(names(ll), function(x) write.xlsx(ll[[x]], 'Workbook.xlsx', sheetName=x, append=TRUE))
```